# Using Ajax for submit a form in Laravel 5.4

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a form and I want to send values to my controller
I wrote this codes but it returns me  MethodNotAllowedHttpException error,
I have a html form 
I send it with POST method
My route is post too

My form:

```
<form method="post" id="form">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <input type="text" name="fname"  id="fname">
    <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname">
    <input type="submit" name="submit-btn" id="submit-btn">
    <h4 id="head"></h4>
</form>
```

JS:

```
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });


    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#form').submit(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url : '{{route('routeName')}}',
                data : {
                    fname: $("input#fname").val(),
                    lname: $("input#lname").val(),
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    //alert(xhr.status);
                    //alert(thrownError);
                },
                success: function(result){
                    $('#head').text(result.head);
                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

My Route :

```
Route::post('routeName' , [
'uses' => 'SomeController@Generate',
'as' => 'routeName']);
```

Controller :

```
    public function Generate(){

    $resp = array();
    $fname= Input::get('fname');
    $lname= Input::get('lname');
    $resp["status"] = "ok";
    return (Response::json($resp));}
```

And the error is :
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUaml.png)

Comment: $('#form').submit(function () { change this to  $('#submit-btn').click(function (e) {  e.preventDefault();

Comment: add this line in header
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />

let me know is this working

Comment: If you watch in devtools, does the POST happen, and does it go to the right URL?  If you view source, is `url : '{{route('routeName')}}',` in your Javascript generated correctly?

Comment: add slash between the route name Route::post('/routeName'

Comment: @Shibon I tried all of them ,and csrf was ok

Comment: @Don'tPanic yes now I have 500 Internal Server Error and I checked console and seems its redirected to right url

Comment: There is error in your controller

Comment: @Shibon I checked it without Ajax and controller worked well and did my job, now when I add Ajax gives me error

Comment: comment all lines inside function and just echo "here";  and see the console response

Comment: @Shibon same errors, XHR failed loading: POST "http://127.0.0.1:8000/MyRoute". and POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/MyRoute 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: add dataType: 'JSON', after url in ajax

Comment: error with your url in ajx use url instead of route

Comment: @Shibon same errors again

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
</script>

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#form').submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); //**** to prevent normal form submission and page reload

            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url : '{{route('routeName')}}',
                data : {
                    fname: $("input#fname").val(),
                    lname: $("input#lname").val(),
                },
                success: function(result){
                    console.log(result);
                    $('#head').text(result.status);
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    //alert(xhr.status);
                    //alert(thrownError);
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

Add `Request` in controller method `Generate`

```
public function Generate(Request $request){

    $resp = array();
    $fname = $request->fname;
    $lname = $request->lname;

    $resp["status"] = "ok";
    return Response::json($resp);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: and now i checked console and I received 500 Internal Server Error, that's funny I used this code in another project time ago and it was ok and now...

Comment: Are you wrinting ur generate method inside CONTROLLER?

Comment: Why not SomeNameController@Generate

Comment: of course, all functions and routes are correct, I checked it out without ajax and it worked well, what the problem is its about catching the form and values and sending it right to route, but I cant figure it out whats the problem

Comment: for some reasons I had to change names to posting here,yes I used SomeNameController@Generate

Comment: @SreejithBS just posting code without an explanation is not a good answer.  Describe what you have done, and why this should help.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the following:

`url : '{{url('routeName')}}',`

and

`return Response::json($resp);`

don't forget to prevent the default submit event

```
$('#form').submit(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
..........
```

and change:

```
 $('#head').text(result.status);
```

Comment: what didn't work, the ajax?the php,what error do you have?

Comment: the main error is MethodNotAllowedHttpException , but after adding preventDefault() it didn't work at all

Comment: can you check the console?do you know where the console is?what errors do you have there , make sure you have a #head element and change in the success function to return the status  `$('#head').text(result.status);`

Comment: please tell me about console ,thanks, and yes I have #head element but the problem is in routing, I get MethodNotAllowedHttpException error that seems like my route is Get but I wrote it definitely in Post, part of laravels Long maybe useless error : at RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('GET', 'HEAD'))

Comment: @PooyaPoorian from what i can tell you are new to ajax, if when you submit the page you are redireting then you aren't doing ajax,to see javascript errors you need to go to the developer tools of your browser ctr+shift+i and you have there a console tab with the errors

Comment: its 500 Internal Server Error, if there is any page that shows more details at inspect and console tell me and i post it from there

Comment: go to the network tab, click submit, you should see a xhr request, click it and see the preview tab, take a screenshot of that